# Print all cells independently at once

Tags: printing

Is there any way to print out to pdf file, in sequence, all cells independently? I have literally hundreds of cells that need to be printed in that way. Selecting each cell and "Print Selections" takes me ages before I finish.

Answer (score 2):

A simple suggestion, assuming you want each cell in a separate file:

```
cellCounter = 1;
Map[
 Export[
   StringJoin["cell-", ToString[cellCounter++], ".pdf"],
   NotebookRead[#]] &, 
 Cells[]];
```

and the resulting file corresponding to this cell:

[image: cell export]

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. It's possible to print out cells "In" and "Out" together (including labels). Now, each of them is printed to separated file.

Comment: @thomas perhaps add these requirements to your question? I'm not much of a notebook programmer...

Comment: @thomas Consider `Split[Cells[], 
 MemberQ[Cells[CellStyle -> {"Input"}], #1] && 
   MemberQ[Cells[CellStyle -> {"Output"}], #2] &]` and [`"CellLabelsToTags"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/frontendobject/CellLabelsToTags.html)

Comment: @cormullion: Ised the above code and get the pdf files but I cannot find the PDFs to print. Where are they stored?