# Saving all cell-groups to pdfs with filenames

Tags: front-end, export, notebooks, cells, pdf-format

I'm trying to programmatically save all input-output cell groups in a given notebook as automatically named pdfs. Is there a way to provide the filename, and save it as a PDF with cell labels but not brackets (just like "File" ► "Save Selection As...").

This is the closest I came but it misses the cell labels:

```
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Previous, CellGroup, 2];
FrontEnd`SaveSelectionAs["~/out.pdf", EvaluationNotebook[], "PDF"]
```

This question's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28552/print-all-cells-independently-at-once/28555#28555) doesn't print the cell labels either, but the comments look like they might have a clue, not sure how to use `"CellLabelsToTags"` though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override the [`Notebook`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Notebook) level [`CellLabelAutoDelete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellLabelAutoDelete) setting. Try the following:

```
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[],Previous,CellGroup,2];
Internal`WithLocalSettings[
    CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], CellLabelAutoDelete] = False,
    FrontEnd`SaveSelectionAs["~/out.pdf", EvaluationNotebook[], "PDF"],
    CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], CellLabelAutoDelete] = Inherited
]
```

---

If you want to control other Notebook options, you can instead control the options of the FrontEnd session:

```
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[],Previous,CellGroup,2];
Internal`WithLocalSettings[
    CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, CellLabelAutoDelete] = False;
    CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, ShowCellBracket] = False,
    FrontEnd`SaveSelectionAs["~/out.pdf", EvaluationNotebook[], "PDF"],
    CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, CellLabelAutoDelete] = Inherited;
    CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, ShowCellBracket] = Inherited
]
```

You can also call `ExportPacket` directly, the function that `` FrontEnd`SaveSelectionAs `` ultimately calls:

```
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[],Previous,CellGroup,2];
Internal`WithLocalSettings[
    CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, CellLabelAutoDelete] = False,
    FrontEndExecute @ ExportPacket[
        Notebook[{NotebookRead[EvaluationNotebook[]]}, ShowCellBracket->False],
        "PDF",
        "~/out.pdf"
    ],
    CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, CellLabelAutoDelete] = Inherited
]
```

The `ExportPacket` approach allows you to directly insert Notebook options into the Notebook object.

Comment: Brilliant solution! and what if I want to disable the cell brackets? Changing "File > Printing Settings > Printing Options" doesn't disable them.